# spinner получение результатов

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter, progress-bar, android-spinner

Есть spinner ,так же есть RecyclerView,через адаптер добавляю в RecyclerView TextView(Год) и ProgressBar(рейтинг продажи за год) при выборе в спинере например 2 позиции(продажа автомобилей) progressBar должен получить данную позицию и сразу же изменится.ВОТ в чем проблема как это реализовать?
Я пытался делать так

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position==0)
            {
                mCount=10;
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Потом просто передавал эти значения но ничего не происходило.

```
public class PCAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PCAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<PC> dataSet;
    private Boolean check=true;
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView word,meaning,tdp,CoresThreads,Socket, Segment,Source,tv_progress_horizontal,e1,e2;
        ProgressBar progressBar1;

        RelativeLayout expandable,cv1;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.expandable= (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);
            this.cv1= (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv1);
            this.word= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordtext);

            this.progressBar1= (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            this.tv_progress_horizontal= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_progress_horizontal);

            this.meaning = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.meaningtext);
            this.tdp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tdp);
            this.CoresThreads = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CoresThreads);
            this.Socket = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Socket);
            this.Segment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Segment);
            this.Source = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Source);
            this.e1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.e1);
            this.e2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.e2);
        }
    }

    public PCAdapter(ArrayList<PC> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
    }

    @Override
    public PCAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view_row1, parent, false);

        final PCAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new PCAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(check)
                {
                    myViewHolder.expandable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    myViewHolder.expandable.animate()
                            .alpha(1.0f)
                            .setDuration(1000);
                    check=false;
                }
                else{
                    myViewHolder.cv1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.asa1);
                    myViewHolder.expandable.animate()
                            .alpha(0.0f)
                            .setDuration(000);
                    myViewHolder.expandable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    check=true;
                }
            }
        });

        return myViewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PCAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        TextView word1= holder.word;
        TextView tv_progress_horizontal1= holder.tv_progress_horizontal;
        ProgressBar progressBar1= holder.progressBar1;
        TextView meaning1 = holder.meaning;
        TextView tdp1 = holder.tdp;
        TextView CoresThreads1 = holder.CoresThreads;
        TextView Socket1 = holder.Socket;
        TextView Segment1 = holder.Segment;
        TextView Source1 = holder.Source;

        TextView e11 = holder.e1;
        TextView e21 = holder.e2;


        word1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getWord());
        tv_progress_horizontal1.setText(String.valueOf(dataSet.get(listPosition).getF()));
        progressBar1.setProgress(dataSet.get(listPosition).getProgress());
        meaning1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getMeaning());
        tdp1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getTdp());
        CoresThreads1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getCoresThreads());
        Socket1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getSocket());
        Segment1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getSegment());
        Source1.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getSource());
        e11.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getE1());
        e21.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getE2());

        ProgressBarAnimation anim = new ProgressBarAnimation(progressBar1, 0,dataSet.get(listPosition).getProgress() );
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        progressBar1.startAnimation(anim);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent;;
    private int mCount=0;
    private ArrayList<PC> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PCAdapter mAdapter;

    PC movie;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abba);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new PCAdapter(movieList);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String[] years1 = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> langAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FilterFinish.this, R.layout.spinner_text, years1 );
        langAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown);
        spinner1.setAdapter(langAdapter1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0)
                {
                    mCount=10;
                    Toast.makeText(FilterFinish.this, "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        movie = new PC("  ",mCount,mCount, "", "", "", "", "", "","","");
        movieList.add(movie);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас не изменился список movie переданный адаптеру и поэтому вызов mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); не дает результатов.

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position==0)
            {
                // здесь нужно изменить значения mCount в элементов вашего списка  movie 
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: не совсем понял.

Comment: напишите мне на почту данные для подключения к вам через теам вивер и помогу сделать. martsinkevych@gmail.com